# Collision detection works, but will not move my character below the collision rectangle only if I jump my character on top of it

Tags: java, collision

The problem I have is my collision between Robot,rect and drainpipe. Groundset works but only moves the character to the ground once the character jumps onto the collision. Otherwise the character will just hover at 450 which is what the previous collision does.

when robot.rect hits

```
///////////////// THIS BIT IN MY ROBOT.CLASS ////////////////////

if (Robot.rect.intersects(drainpipe.groundset)) {

            GROUND = 495;

         }

/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Image;
import java.awt.Rectangle;
import java.util.Set;


public class Robot {

// Constants are Here
final int JUMPSPEED = -15;
final int MOVESPEED = 5;
static int GROUND = 495;

private int centerX = 100;
private int centerY = GROUND;
private boolean jumped = false;
private boolean movingLeft = false;
private boolean movingRight = false;
private boolean normal = false;



public static Background bg1 = StartingClass.getBg1();              
public static Background bg2 = StartingClass.getBg2();

private int speedX = 0;
private int speedY = 1;
public int x, y, width, height, right;
public int vX;
public int vY;


public static Rectangle rect = new Rectangle(0, 0, 0, 0);
public static Rectangle rect2 = new Rectangle(0, 0, 0, 0);
public static int setCenterY;
public static int setCenterX;

 public static Background getBg1() {
    return bg1;
}

public static void setBg1(Background bg1) {
    Robot.bg1 = bg1;
}

public static Background getBg2() {
    return bg2;
}

public static void setBg2(Background bg2) {
    Robot.bg2 = bg2;
}

public int getJUMPSPEED() {
    return JUMPSPEED;
}

public int getMOVESPEED() {
    return MOVESPEED;
}

public int getGROUND() {
    return GROUND;
}

public void update() {


 if(rect.intersects(drainpipe.rectdt)) {

 GROUND=450;


 System.out.println("mario crossed the TOP line");

  }





// SET CHARACTER TO GO TO THE GROUND


     if (Robot.rect.intersects(drainpipe.groundset)) {

        GROUND = 495;

     }




    //speedX=1;

     // Moves Character or Scrolls Background accordingly.
     if (speedX < 0) {
         centerX += speedX;
     }
     if (speedX == 0 || speedX < 0) {
         bg1.setSpeedX(0);
         bg2.setSpeedX(0);

     }
     if (centerX <= 200 && speedX > 0) {
         centerX += speedX;
     }
     if (speedX > 0 && centerX > 200){
         bg1.setSpeedX(-MOVESPEED);
         bg2.setSpeedX(-MOVESPEED);
     }

     // Updates Y Position
     centerY += speedY;
     if (centerY + speedY >= GROUND) {
         centerY = GROUND;
     }

     // Handles Jumping
     if (jumped == true) {
         speedY += 1;

         if (centerY + speedY >= GROUND) {
             centerY = GROUND;
             speedY = 0;
             jumped = false;
         }

     }

     // Prevents going beyond X coordinate of 0
     if (centerX + speedX <= 60) {
         centerX = 61;
     }

     //sets collision rectangle around the character
rect.setRect(centerX - 65, centerY - 65, 19, 20);
//rect2.setRect(rect.getX(), rect.getY() + 63, 30, 30);

 }






//Sets the movements and keys pressed to make character move

 public void moveRight() {
     if (normal == false) {
         speedX = MOVESPEED;
     }
 }

 public void moveLeft() {
     if (normal == false) {
         speedX = -MOVESPEED;
     }
 }

 public void stopRight() {
     setMovingRight(false);
     stop();
 }

 public void stopLeft() {
     setMovingLeft(false);
     stop();
 }

 private void stop() {
     if (isMovingRight() == false && isMovingLeft() == false) {
         speedX = 0;
     }

     if (isMovingRight() == false && isMovingLeft() == true) {
         moveLeft();
     }

     if (isMovingRight() == true && isMovingLeft() == false) {
         moveRight();
     }

 }

 public void jump() {
     if (jumped == false) {
         speedY = JUMPSPEED;
         jumped = true;
     }

 }

 public int getCenterX() {
     return centerX;
 }

 public int getCenterY() {
     return centerY;
 }

 public boolean isJumped() {
     return jumped;
 }

 public int getSpeedX() {
     return speedX;
 }

 public int getSpeedY() {
     return speedY;
 }

 public void setCenterX(int centerX) {
     this.centerX = centerX;
 }

 public void setCenterY(int centerY) {
     this.centerY = centerY;
 }

 public void setJumped(boolean jumped) {
     this.jumped = jumped;
 }

 public void setSpeedX(int speedX) {
     this.speedX = speedX;
 }

 public void setSpeedY(int speedY) {
     this.speedY = speedY;
 }

 public boolean isnormal() {
     return normal;
 }

 public void setnormal(boolean normal) {
     this.normal = normal;
 }

 public boolean isMovingRight() {
     return movingRight;
 }

 public void setMovingRight(boolean movingRight) {
     this.movingRight = movingRight;
 }

 public boolean isMovingLeft() {
     return movingLeft;
 }

 public void setMovingLeft(boolean movingLeft) {
     this.movingLeft = movingLeft;
 }



public boolean Intersects(Image drainpipe) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return false;
}





 }
```

Comment: I have now fixed this by adding centerY = GROUND; after the command GROUND = 495;  under the intersect section. thanks to anyone that was going to respond :-)